# Are there any USB microphones under $10 that will record talking-volume sound 2-3 meters away?

Tags: microphone

I have several small USB microphones, which work just fine as long as my mouth is within a few inches of the mic's input. However, I am looking for a small and cheap microphone (under $10 from somewhere like Amazon) that doesn't require such close proximity.

Are there any such cheap USB microphones that can record normal volume speaking that takes place 2-3 meters away from the mic? I'm not sure if there is particular term for such a microphone, but feel free to help out with jargon. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I didn't even know there were any USB microphones at all for under $10.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to be too close to the mic, maybe what you're looking for is a Condenser Mic. Dynamic mics usually are less sensitive, so you have to get closer to them. The thing is there's probably no such thing (a condenser) for $10. Not even close as far as I know. Maybe your best option is looking for something used, you might find a cheap one.